# Joining two tables for fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables: recipes and tags, to be used for a fulltext search in a CodeIgniter App. For every 1 recipe, they're is an unlimited number of tags (some examples of tags: tasty, chicken, dinner).

Sample Rows in the recipes table:

### Recipe Id: 1.....Recipe Name: Mo's Chicken Dinner.....

### Recipe Id: 2.....Recipe Name: Mo's Lobster Bisque.....

Sample Rows in the tags table:

### Corresponding Recipe Id: 1.....Tag: Tasty.....

### Corresponding Recipe Id: 2.....Tag: Seafood.....

I want to be able to search for lobster and have recipes that names match "lobster" show up in the search. But I also want to search for "Seafood" and have tags that have a corresponding recipe show up.

Here's my code (which worked for one table fulltext search, before I added the join statements):

```
// Execute our SQL statement and return the result
    $sql = "SELECT recipes.name,recipes.durationtotal
                FROM recipes LEFT JOIN tags ON recipes.id = tags.recipes_id
                WHERE MATCH (recipes.name,tags.tag) AGAINST (?) > 0 AND user_id = ".$id." ORDER BY recipes.name ASC";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($terms, $terms));
    return $query->result();
```

After putting this in, I get the error:

```
Error Number: 1210

Incorrect arguments to MATCH

SELECT recipes.name,recipes.durationtotal FROM recipes LEFT JOIN tags ON recipes.id = tags.recipes_id WHERE MATCH (recipes.name,tags.tag) AGAINST ('f') > 0 AND user_id = 1 ORDER BY recipes.name ASC

Filename: search_model.php

Line Number: 15
```

Line 15 is: `$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($terms, $terms));`

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the tables involved in the search are not MyISAM and you have not set up fulltext indices on the specific column set you are searching against, MATCH AGAINST queries will fail.  I think, since you are searching against columns in different tables, you can't create a fulltext index that spans both tables.  You can try IN BOOLEAN MODE:

```
MATCH (recipes.name,tags.tag) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Boolean mode is a little more forgiving than standard fulltext matching.

Comment: @dethron5000, thanks for the reply, but still get the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You may not be able to do cross-table fulltext searches - I would check the MySQL docs.  You may have to refactor your query into a UNION of two queries that do the fulltext search against the two keys.  You may also want to look at something like SOLR although that's a good bit more work to implement.